# h2o-wave deployment with uvicorn, httpx connection err [Errno 111] Connect call failed

Tags: python-3.7, h2o-wave

I want to run h2o wave with uvicorn command.

in public document (https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/deployment) says
wave run foo == uvicorn foo:main

but in my pycharm terminal,
"wave run foo" works but not "uvicorn foo:main" like below

wave run command
[image]

uvicorn foo:main command
[image]

what is problem??

foo.py code

```
from h2o_wave import site, ui, Q, app, main
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
_localhost = "0.0.0.0"
def _scan_free_port(port = "8000"):
    return port
@app('/demo')
async def serve(q: Q):
    logging.warning('All your base are belong to us')
```

lib version below

- h2o-wave          0.20.0
- starlette         0.13.8
- uvicorn           0.12.2
- httpcore          0.12.3
- httpx             0.16.1
- Python 3.7.5

ps.
in FUTURE, I want to run like below

```
import uvicorn
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('foo:main')
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: See [how to run the Wave server manually](https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/installation-8-20).

Detailed answer:

If you look at [architecture](https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/architecture/), you will notice there are actually 2 servers:

1. Python server - Wave app, the one you are running via uvicorn.
2. Wave server - Go server that acts as a proxy between Wave app and browser.

The reason why `wave run foo` works and `uvicorn foo:main` does not is simply because `wave run` [spawns Wave server under the hood](https://github.com/h2oai/wave/blob/master/py/h2o_wave/cli.py#L89). For deployment though, it's recommended to start both Wave server and Wave app separately to allow for the most flexible configuration.